# Multiple Values in Declared Variable

Tags: sql-server

Currently, my statement is:

```
declare @whscode as nvarchar(10) = 'WELSH'
```

But I need to add more values for that parameter (should be "WELSH" and "WA")

I have tried the following, but neither work:

```
declare @whscode as nvarchar(10) = ('WELSH, WA')
set @whscode = ('WELSH, WA')
```

Comment: Do you want to store multiple values in a single variable?

Comment: use `table variable` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 or `table valued parameters` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: A variable holds a **single** value. Perhaps Erland's discussion of [arrays](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple values into a single variable, you can't do it.

Using the [table variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you can achieve it

```
DECLARE @WHSCODE TABLE (WHSCODE nvarchar(10));

INSERT INTO @WHSCODE (WHSCODE) VALUES ('WELSH'), ('WA');

SELECT WHSCODE FROM @WHSCODE;
```

Working [**demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35e7d5077ebca8887c511edd62575205)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add further value then use `set` with comma separation like

```
   declare @whscode as nvarchar(10) = 'WELSH'
   set @whscode += ', NEW'
```

You may use these value further using `STRING_SPLIT`. 
reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017